# How can I get the source of a file using Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Selenium has a function called getPageSource that will get the source code of the page. I'm looking for the equivalent in Cypress.

I've tried

```
 cy.get('html:root')
 .eq(0)
 .invoke('prop', 'outerHTML')
```

but, it doesn't really return the source of the page. As an example, the source contains `&copy;`, but the above cypress command shows it as ©. I want to see the actual source of the page, what I would see if I were to go to the server and open the file up in any plain text editor like notepad.

Comment: Maybe there is another way. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to take the source and send it to https://validator.w3.org/, https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/, etc. The file is not accessible to the public internet, so I cannot just send the url, so I submit the source instead. This was fairly easy to do in Selenium: getPageSource and then post it to the validation service which would return a response as json which the code would parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naïve answer is to use `string.replaceAll()`

```js
cy.get('html:root')
  .eq(0)
  .invoke('prop', 'outerHTML')
  .then(pageSource => pageSource.replaceAll('©', '&copy;'))
```

See [dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for a reference chart.

But I have a feeling there is a conversion function somewhere that does any and all occurrences.

---

**Getting the equivalent of "View page source"***

```js
cy.request(my-url)
  .its('body')          // NB the response body, not the body of your page
  .then(content => {

    // send content to validator.w3.org
    // you can probably cy.visit('validator.w3.org') and manipulate the 
    // validation page, pasting in content value as required

  })
```